# C: Iterate through an array of strings

Tags: c

I'm currently learning C and am struggling with how to iterate through an array of strings.
Let's just say I define an array, like so:

```
char* argv_custom[] = {"--debug", "--verbose", "--test", "--ultimate"};
```

Now, how would I go about determining the number of strings within argv_custom? (e.g. argc_custom)
Am I going the right way about this in the first place? Also, is it possible to do something like:

*Pseudocode*

```
if ('--debug' in argv_custom) { // do stuff }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Now, how would I go about determining the number of strings within argv_custom?

The [canonical way](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arraynels.html):

```
int argc_custom = sizeof(argv_custom) / sizeof(argv_custom[0]);
```

**Note:** This **only** works on the array itself, as soon as you have a pointer (such as if you pass `argv_custom` to a function), it no longer works:

```
char **p = argv_custom;
int argc_custom = sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]);  // No me gusta
```

---

> is it possible to do something like: ...

There's no shortcut.  You would have to iterate over each string, and do `strcmp`.  Of course, you could (and probably should) wrap this behaviour into a function.

Comment: If you're into saving keystrokes (or subscribe to the idea that `sizeof` is not a function) you can write the expression as `sizeof argv_custom / sizeof *argv_custom`. That's my preferred form, I like how it omits the magical constant `0`, too.

Answer (score 3):

you can do `sizeof(argv_custom)/sizeof(argv_custom[0])`. This calculates the total length of the array divided by the size of every single element.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this question quite a few times and from what I've found my favorite solution is to just iterate through the pointer until `null`.  `sizeof` stops working as soon as you start using functions and passing the arrays around.

Here's a paradigm I've used time and time again in my assignments and it's been really helpful.  The exact same thing can be used for getting the length of a `cstring` or iterating through its characters.

```
char* argv_custom[] = {"--debug", "--verbose", "--test", "--ultimate"};
char **temp = argv_custom;
int size = 0;
while (*temp) {
    ++size;
    ++temp;
}
```

This is not preferred over using `sizeof`, however it's an alternative when you want to loop through it.